# Reinicio de apache en otra ruta

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, centos, httpd

Tengo la siguiente consulta, me han dado un servidor donde tuve que instalar certificados digitales, pero al momento de reiniciar el servicio apache me salió el siguiente error:

> -bash-4.1# service httpd restart Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ] Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could
>   not bind to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: make_sock:
>   could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available,
>   shutting down Unable to open logs
>                                                              [FAILED]

Pero al revisar los procesos corriendo con ps aux veo esto:

> apache   10607  0.0  0.1  37928 16088 ?        S    17:16   0:00
>   /usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/bin/httpd -k start apache   10771  0.0  0.1 
>   37124 15164 ?        S    17:18   0:00
>   /usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/bin/httpd -k start apache   10773  0.0  0.1 
>   37444 15488 ?        S    17:18   0:00
>   /usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/bin/httpd -k start apache   10774  0.0  0.1 
>   37380 15356 ?        S    17:18   0:00
>   /usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/bin/httpd -k start apache   10776  0.0  0.1 
>   37260 15340 ?        S    17:18   0:00
>   /usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/bin/httpd -k start apache   10816  0.0  0.1 
>   37316 15192 ?        S    17:19   0:00
>   /usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/bin/httpd -k start apache   10818  0.0  0.1 
>   37404 15536 ?        S    17:19   0:00
>   /usr/local/httpd-2.2.25/bin/httpd -k start
>   ¿Donde veo que la ruta por defecto de apache no es la misma, como puedo reiniciar el servicio ??.

Considerando también que cuando hago un httpd -v me sale lo siguiente:

**-bash-4.1# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)**

**pero la version que dice la web es *2.2.25***

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que ya existe algo escuchando en el puerto `80` de ahí el error de:

```
Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

Verifica que puede estar escuchando ahí con el comando:

```
netstat -putan | grep 80
```

Eso te puede dar una idea de que tienes ahí. Veras algo así:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.3.151:80        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11416/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 192.168.17.151:80       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11416/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11416/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11416/nginx: worker 
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80              x.x.x.x:39954           TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80              x.x.x.x:64463           TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      6952/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 192.168.17.151:8080     192.168.16.5:34078      TIME_WAIT   -
```

Yo ahí puedo ver que hay un `nginx` en el puerto 80 y un `httpd` en el 8080.

Después con `ps aux | grep <servicio>` podrías ver si existe un `nginx` o un apache, que en `CentOS` ese servicio se llama `httpd`.

Probablemente tengas ya un servicio de esos dos corriendo en el servidor.

Una vez que sepas qué está corriendo, tendrás que parar el servicio para arrancar el tuyo o configurar el servicio en otro puerto.

Dos servicios no pueden estar intentando escuchar en el mismo puerto.

Si necesitas eso, la solución seria tener un proxy que envíe las peticiones a cada servicio dependiendo de los criterios que establezcas.